# SQL Anywhere error: error occurred during sharedmemory connection attempt

Tags: database, shared-memory, sqlanywhere

I have been writing queries for an SQL anywhere 12 database.  I was able to connect to the database using Aqua Data Studio.  However, my free trial is up and I don't want to pay $500 just to write some queries.  Every other software I have tried (Sybase Central, ODBC, Altova DatabaseSpy, SQL anywhere Client) all give me the same error: an error occured during the sharedmemory connection attempt.  I have no idea why this is happening, and I have even tried turning off the "use shared memory connection" on my DB but to no avail.

Does anyone know why Aqua Data studio was able to connect but no other software can?  Is there a way to fix the SharedMemory issue?

Is there another software that would be able to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure in this case, but SQL Anywhere does support the concept of an "authenticated" database, which means that only client applications recognized by the server as being allowed can connect. That is likely the case here.

*Note: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere Engineering.*

Comment: Is there any way of knowing what programs can access the DB?

Comment: Sorry, I think I've misunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about a free trial of SQL Anywhere (though I didn't think we had such a thing). But it looks like you were talking about a free trial of the Aqua product. Can you add ";LOG=client.txt" to your connection string and see if there is a more specific error message in the client.txt file?

Comment: this is what was returned:

09:15:14 Attempting to connect using:
UID=DBA;PWD=********;DBN=***;DBF=****;ServerName=****;CON='***';ASTOP=YES;INT=NO;ENC=NONE;LOG=client.txt

09:15:14 Attempting to connect to a running server...

09:15:14 Attempting SharedMemory connection (no sasrv.ini cached address)

09:15:14 Failed to connect over SharedMemory

09:15:14 Cannot connect to server


Looks like I'm missing an ini file?  is there a way to fix that?

Comment: How did you start the server? Is it running on the same machine? What platform are you running on?

Comment: I'm running on Windows server 2008.   It is running on the same machine.  The server was installed and used by a 3rd party application.  I have manually restarted the server multiple times via the 3rd party server manager software.

Comment: OK. Try stopping the server and then running the client application again. The client should start the server itself, then connect. If it doesn't, post the last part of the client.txt.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46256/discussion-between-graeme-perrow-and-fuzzerker)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  There were two servers running with the same name, so the "shared memory" couldn't figure out which one to connect to, I had to start up one server, then the second, then shut down the first.

Comment: How did you shut down a server and from where?